# Do something when view changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm developing an iOS application with a Tab View Controller and two complementary views.
One of these uses CoreLocation API to get current speed and because of this, it uses a lot of battery.

I know that with:

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

I can stop the speed updating, but I want to do this when the user change view.

Is this possible?

Comment: give this line of code in button action method.

Comment: By "Tab View Controller" do you mean `UITabBarController` ?

Comment: Yes, `UITabBarController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your ViewController of tab item where you want location update

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    

    // Start location manager
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Stop location manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

**When your ViewController appear location manager get's start and stop when disappear
.**

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`, when the action to change the page performed.

Comment: Action means to change the page you are calling any function or performing some method to change the page.Just add the [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; this when the page change method is performed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the delegate of the `UITabbarController`. Then you get:

`- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;`

and you can return YES and stop the locationManager

---

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    tabBarController.delegate = self; //you need an iboutlet to get the tabbar
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
    if([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(locationManager)])
        [[viewController locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation]; //your viewController needs to expose the locationManager as a property
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: it seems this is old school ^^ remember viewWillDisappear wasn't called.. but it works now! cool